# shortest distance between nodes in a prunned torus Network

Tags: graph-theory

I am not a mathematician, but I am facing some mathematical challenge.
I came across such a network for the first time which is shown in this figure.
I am not sure, but I think it is called as Prunned Torus.

Now, I want to calculate the shortest distance between any two nodes. In mesh network, calculating manhattan distance is an easy way to calculate shortest distance between two nodes. Similarly I would like to know if there is a method to calculate shortest distance in such kind of networks. Any pointers will be appreciated.

Thank You !

[image]

Comment: Your picture is bit strange, because usually torus networks has equal number of connections for each node. For pruned 3d torus the number is 4, but some your nodes (C22, C27, C4, C9 ...) has only 3 connections. Some examples here http://www.ece.ucsb.edu/~parhami/pubs_folder/parh04-cic-hex-pr-torus.pdf at page 4. PS: some calculations of average for pruned 2d torus: http://www.ece.ucsb.edu/~parhami/pubs_folder/parh01-ieeetpds-hnycmb-dmnd.pdf may be here too http://www.ece.ucsb.edu/~parhami/pubs_folder/parh04-mcm-four-torus-nets.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The [shortest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) is one of the standard graph problems; the wikipedia page lists standard algorithms for solving several variations, such as the [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm)

Comment: sorry to say, but i was looking for some formula which can be used to calculate the distance. for example manhattan distance formula.